# Merging datas from an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90
            [name] => Paul
            [company] => Google
            [date] => 2018-01-06
            [total] => 100.00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 90
            [name] => Paul
            [company] => Google
            [date] => 2018-07-06
            [total] => 100.00
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 89
            [name] => Ethan
            [company] => Yahoo
            [date] => 2018-07-10
            [total] => 1140.00
        )
)
```

I need to create a new array from the previous one by merging `id` and `name` if they are the same.

The desired output should be:

```
[[
    [id] => 90
    [name] => Paul
    [company] => Google,
    [data] => [
        [date] => 2018-01-06,
        [total] => 100.00
    ],
    [
        [date] => 2018-07-06,
        [total] => 100.00
    ],
], [
    [id] => 89
    [name] => Ethan
    [company] => Yahoo
    [data] => [
        [date] => 2018-07-10,
        [total] => 1140.00
    ]
]]
```

What I have tried before:

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $data){
    $output[$data['id']][] = $data;
    $output[$data['name']][] = $data;
    $output[$data['company']][] = $data;
}
```

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Comment: so, you need no duplicates or just checking 2 consecutive elements if they are same is enough?

Comment: Also, if you're getting the data from the database, I have the feeling you can solve this problem by modifying your query instead of php code. It may be more efficient

Comment: @Lemures, I need to check only the `id` but I do not want to duplicate each time the same infos `name` and `company`.

Comment: Your desired output is invalid. "Google" cannot be followed by an array. That array must be assigned to a new property.

Comment: Once again, I suggest you rethink you sql query. If you show me the table structure, I might help you.

Comment: It also looks like the ID value is the key, and determines the name uniquely. Please clarify.

Comment: @trincot the desired output also has duplicate keys..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be something like what you're looking for:

```
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    if (empty($resp[$a['id']])) {
        $resp[$a['id']] = [
            'id' => $a['id'],
            'name' => $a['name'],
            'company' => $a['company'],
            'data' => []
        ];
    }
    $resp[$a['id']]['data'][] = [
        'date' => $a['date'],
        'total' => $a['total']
    ];
}
```

This is assuming that you only care about grouping the date and total into a repeated company and name.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: How can I remove the first level of information? `[90] => Array...` and start directly with `(   [KDX_Id] => 90` ?

Comment: What does the `KDX_Id` mean? Do you just want your array to start at `0` instead of the `id`?

Comment: Yes. To make it minimal.

Comment: You can use `array_values()`. After the loop, you can call `$resp = array_values($resp)`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again.